# Difference between return 0 and return 1

Tags: c, cygwin

My professor posted

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // enter code here

    printf("Test 1: trying odd(3) AND even(2)...\n");
    printf("%d\n", odd(3) && even(2));
    printf("Test 2: trying odd(3) OR even(2)...\n");
    printf("%d\n", odd(3) || even(2));
    printf("Test 3: trying odd(4) AND even(7)...\n");
    printf("%d\n", odd(4) && even(7));
    printf("Test 4: trying odd(4) OR even(7)...\n");
    printf("%d\n", odd(4) || even(7));

    return 0;
}

int odd(int n)
{
    printf("in odd!\n");

    return n % 2 == 1;
}

int even(int r)
{
    printf("in even!\n");

    return r % 2 == 0;
}
```

as an assignment asking why lines 2 and 3 only return in odd! but 1 and 4 return in odd! and in even! I'm unsure as to why as I don't know the difference between the Return 1 and Return 0 commands. From what I can gather Return 1 will always return the value (in this case in odd!) but return 0 will only return it if it satisfies a certain condition?

Also: does the code int length(char *name,int start,double finish): return the length of a word in characters as a real number?

Thanks in advance to anyone that decides to help me.

Comment: I have fixed the indendantion of your code. You have to indent the code by using 4 character spacing, or well by selecting all the code and then click on the button "Code Sample".

Comment: @pablo1977 you call that fixing?

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst: I just added indentation. I can improve it more, if you want. But I prefer to respect the way in that the OP write his own code. I will not give programming style lessons here.

Comment: Search about "short circuit evaluation in C".

Comment: Your professor is giving you an important lesson about short circuit. You will be very smart if you spend good time to learns this topic deeply.

Answer (score 4):

This is called "[Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)".

> ...in which the second argument is executed or evaluated only if the first argument does not suffice to determine the value of the expression...

Therefore, you have to figure out what will these two functions `odd` and `even` return:

1. odd(): If n % 2 == 1 , return 1, otherwise 0
2. even(): If n % 2 == 0 , return 1, otherwise 0

And in the main() function,

1. `odd(3)` **AND** `even(2)`: `odd(3)` return 1, and check the return value of `even(2)`, therefore the `even()` is called.
2. `odd(3)` **OR** `even(2)`: `odd(3)` return 1, because of 'short-circuit evaluation', it doesn't need to check the `even(2)`, therefore the `even()` isn't called.
3. `odd(4)` **AND** `even(7)`: `odd(4)` return 0, because of 'short-circuit evaluation', it doesn't need to check the `even(7)`, therefore the `even()` isn't called.
4. `odd(4)` **OR** `even(7)`: `odd(4)` return 0, and check the return value of `even(7)`, therefore the `even()` is called.

Answer (score 2):

when evaluating a logical expressions, it checks the condition one by one and whenever the whole expression is known (whatever the remaining are) it stops evaluating them.

**Example**

```
unsigned char a = 1;  // true
unsigned char b = 0;  // false
```

*case 1*

```
if (a && b) printf("Yes");
```

- check `a`: yes it is `true`
- check `b`: no it is not `true`

Result: the expression is wrong and it doesn't print `Yes`

*case 2*

```
if (a && !b) printf("Yes");
```

- checks `a`: yes it is `true`
- checks `b`: yes it is `false`

Result: the expression is right and it prints `Yes`

*case 3*

```
if (a || b) printf("Yes");
```

- checks `a`: yes it is `true`
- checks `b` ?!!! WHY? no need to check `b` since the whole expression result is known only by checking `a`, do you agree?

Result: checks `a`and print `Yes` without even checking `b`

Project that on your code now ;)

Answer (score 1):

The logical Boolean algebra operators AND and OR (`&&` and `||`) in C operate with an optimization known as [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

This is how the optimization works.

Imagine that you came up with a rule for yourself:

You will only date someone if they own a `cat` AND a `dog` AND a `fish`.

Now imagine you start talking to someone that you may be interested in dating. They say:

> Well, I have a cat, I don't have a fish, but I do have a dog.

When did you stop paying attention to what they said? As soon as they said that they didn't have a `fish`, because as soon as they said that, they **broke** your "AND" rule. So, the rest of the sentence is completely irrelevant. This is short-circuiting AND.

Now imagine that you changed your rule:

You will only date someone if they own a `cat` OR a `dog` OR a `fish`.

Now imagine you start talking to someone that you may be interested in dating. They say:

> Well, I don't have a cat, I have a fish, and I don't have a dog.

When did you stop paying attention to what they said? As soon as they said that they had a `fish`, because as soon as they said that, they **satisfied** your "OR" rule. So, the rest of the sentence is completely irrelevant. This is short-circuiting OR.

Short-circuit evaluation is a performance optimization for evaluating logical expressions.

In your example, the `even()` function returns `true` if the number passed to it is even, and the `odd()` function returns `true` if the number passed to it is even. Otherwise these functions return `false`. Look at each of the Boolean expressions and notice when short-circuit evaluation must occur.

Answer (score 1):

Return 0; - the function returns 0.
Return 1; - the function returns 1.

In your case odd function returns 1 when number (n) is odd and 0 when the number is even.
This is done by "asking" if the reminder when dividing by 2 equels 1.

Also  even function returns 1 when number (r) is even, and 0 when the number is odd.
This is done by "asking" if the reminder when dividing by 2 equels 0.

In your main function, and (&&)  and or logical operations are done, on the results of the return values of odd and even functions.

Example:odd(3) return 1, even(2) return 1 then 1&&1 equals 1  (the result).

Answer (score 0):

There's also another way to test for even values for integral types.

```
int IsOdd(int x) { return (x & 1); }
int IsEven(int x) { return !(x & 1); }
```

If the least-significant bit is set, the number is odd. If not, it's even. This simply tests that bit. Just throwing this out there so you can eliminate the modulus operation... it's another option. Not an answer to your question, but I can't comment so...

Answer (score 0):

As we know 0 indicates false-ness, 1 indicates true-ness. And the return part tells the compiler that the function must return the evaluated result to the caller module.

So, a return 1 means signal the caller module about a successful execution of the called module (with the aid of a Non-Zero quantity i.e. 1) 
whereas,

return 0 presents a flag showing that there was some error/anomaly that led to the termination of the called module. So, in this case stderr shall be used to give details about such error.